# Problems getting "with selection" to work

Tags: excel, vba

I'm working on a excel vba code to import and manipulate some data from CSV-file. Suddenly a part of my code didn't work any more though it had worked without problems before.

It is about range.select and afterward with selection.Interior.Pattern = xlSolid

I have tried to copy the same small part of the code to a different workbook and here it work just perfect.

```
Dim iPhase As Integer
iPhase = Application.WorksheetFunction.CountIf(Range("A:A"), "Phase")
Dim h As Integer
h = 1

Range("A6").Select

Do Until h > iPhase
    Cells.Find(What:="Phase", after:=ActiveCell, LookIn:=xlFormulas, LookAt _
    :=xlPart, SearchOrder:=xlByRows, SearchDirection:=xlNext, MatchCase:= _
    False, SearchFormat:=False).Activate
    ActiveSheet.Range(ActiveCell, ActiveCell.Offset(0, 16)).Select
    With selection.Interior
        .Pattern = xlSolid
        .Interior.PatternColorIndex = xlAutomatic
        .Interior.ThemeColor = xlThemeColorAccent6
        .Interior.TintAndShade = 0
        .Interior.PatternTintAndShade = 0
    End With
    With selection.Font
        .Bold = True
    End With
    h = h + 1
Loop
```

I get a compile error: Expected function or variable @"selection.interior"

Comment: Don't use `.Select` and `.Selection`: [How to avoid using Select in Excel VBA](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10714251/how-to-avoid-using-select-in-excel-vba).

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to avoid using Select in Excel VBA](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10714251/how-to-avoid-using-select-in-excel-vba)

Comment: Also two more things **[1.]** You are assuming that `Cells.Find` will return a result. Check if it found something or not. You may want to see [THIS](http://www.siddharthrout.com/index.php/2018/01/05/find-and-findnext-in-excel-vba/) on how to do that **[2.]**  `I get a compile error: Expected function or variable @"selection.interior"` If you copied your code and pasted it as it is then your `selection` has a small `s`. That means you have declared a variable/module/class etc with the same name. You need to avoid that as well...

Answer (score 0):

The comments already identify the issues with your code; but here is an alternative using `Filter` and `SpecialCells` to select the visible data. Comments are contained in the code.

```
Sub FliterWithConditionalFormatting()
Dim rng As Range

'properly defing and reference your workbook and worksheet, change as requiried
Set rng = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Sheet1").Range("A1").CurrentRegion

'The WITH..END WITH statement allows you to shorten your code and avoid using SELECT and ACTIVATE
With rng
     .AutoFilter Field:=1, Criteria1:="Phase", Operator:=xlAnd 'filter the rng

    'set the range, to conditionally format only the visible data, skipping the header row
    With .Range(Cells(2, 1), Cells(rng.Rows.Count, 17)).SpecialCells(xlCellTypeVisible)

        With .Interior
            .Pattern = xlSolid
            .PatternColorIndex = xlAutomatic
            .Color = xlThemeColorAccent6
            .TintAndShade = 0
            .PatternTintAndShade = 0
        End With

        With .Font
            .Bold = True
        End With
    End With

    .AutoFilter 'Remove the filter
End With
End Sub
```